# POSIX named pipe (fifo) drops record in nonblocking mode

Tags: c, linux, posix, named-pipes

I am using POSIX named pipes (fifos) to send records from one or more threads to be read by another thread (only one thread does the reading).  However, the 83rd record out of 100 records is simply dropped.  The client core calls write and the return value is correctly reported as the length of the record (720 bytes) so the client (writer) core confirms that the record is sent, but switching to the reader core in gdb debug mode with scheduler-locking on, I cycle through reading the few previous records and then read fails -- no record in the pipe, even though the client (writer) core confirmed the write.

The pipe capacity is 65,536 bytes (by default in Linux).  I assume the pipe contents are reduced by 1 record for each record read, so at the point where the 83rd record is dropped I have about 5 prior records in the pipe, or 3600 bytes -- not enough to fill the pipe.

I opened the pipes in nonblocking mode because when I opened them in blocking mode both ends froze.  According to the man pages at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html, "The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed.  Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also."  My problem is that both ends block and won't go further.  It also says, "Under Linux, opening a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in blocking and nonblocking mode.  POSIX leaves this behavior undefined."

The code on each end is simple:

```
int64_t fifo_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count) {

    int status_write = write(fd, buf, count);

    return status_write; }

int64_t fifo_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) {

    int status_read = read(fd, buf, count); 

    return status_read; }
```

The C functions are called from my NASM program:

```
mov rdi,[fifo_read_fd]
lea rsi,[fifo_buffer]
mov rdx,720
call fifo_read wrt ..plt

mov rdi,[fifo_write_fd]
mov rsi,[rbp-24]
mov rdx,720 ; bytes
push r11
push rcx
call fifo_write wrt ..plt
pop rcx
pop r11
```

My questions are:

1. What could cause the dropped record?  It does not look like pipe capacity unless the pipe is not emptied with the read of each record -- even all 83 records would take 59760 bytes, below the 65K pipe capacity in Linux.  It could be due to nonblocking mode, but if the pipe is not full there would be no reason to block.
2. How can I open both ends in blocking mode (given that both ends freeze, each waiting for the other), and are there any problems would I have with blocking mode?
3. I could open both ends in read/write mode because my code only writes on from one or more threads on one end and reads from 1 thread (only) on the other end.  While "POSIX leaves this behavior undefined" are there any reasons not open both ends in read/write mode in this situation?

I have not posted any other code with this question (except as above)  because I'm only looking for ideas on the best way to handle the problem of a  dropped record in the case I described.

Comment: Trying adding  attribute [packed](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) to struct, and check if you are able to send more data.

Comment: I'm reading and writing a record of 90 qwords -- 720 bytes.

Comment: `int status_read` must be `ssize_t status_read`. It won't fix your problem, but eliminating all potential errors is a good excercise.

Comment: @Tony Tannous - add it to what struct?  I don't have a struct.

Comment: I'm curious about the "both ends block[ed]" symptom with blocking open()s.  The first opener thread should only block until its complementing mate (a reader for a blocked-on-open writer, or vice versa) also opens, at which point the blocked thread would resume execution.  Under what circumstance are both blocked, and indefinitely?

Comment: To me it was a classic Mexican standoff -- nobody can proceed because each side is waiting for the other.  Maxim Egorushkin was correct in his answer below -- that problem is not present with UNIX sockets.  I suggest a stream socket instead of a datagram socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple writers using one FIFO sending messages of 720 bytes. POSIX only requires writes of `PIPE_BUF` (512 bytes, normally) to be atomic. That means that longer writes can get interleaved by writes from other threads and get corrupted.

Regardless of `PIPE_BUF` size, pipes are streams and they don't have a notion of a message, and that means you need to delimit messages yourself, which your code doesn't do. In other words, your reader code cannot possibly recover the individual messages when there are multiple writers.

You may like to use a [Unix datagram socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) instead. Each message into a Unix datagram socket is an atomic message and it gets written and read completely in one syscall (`sendto` and `recvfrom`).

Comment: According to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html, "On Linux,       PIPE_BUF is 4096 bytes."  But I will check into Unix datagram sockets -- it sounds more performant.

Comment: @RTC222 Added a note that `PIPE_BUF` is somewhat irrelevant for your problem.

Comment: I believe that where the record sizes are fixed (720 bytes), no delimiter is needed.  But datagram sockets may solve this problem, and it does sound like better performance.

Comment: @RTC222 Pipes being a stream means that `write` may write less and `read` may read less than requested. Unlike a Unix datagram socket. They should write at least `PIPE_BUF` but then your reads must be reading the exact message size, which must be less than or equal to `PIPE_BUF`. That's too much of a hassle, which you avoid with Unix datagram sockets completely. FIFOs are one of the oldest IPCs, Unix sockets are much more modern, flexible and powerful. Especially datagram Unix sockets that allow to read and write complete messages atomically. I am risking repeating myself, though.