# Python avoid partial writes with non-blocking write to named pipe

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, posix

I am running python3.8 on linux.

In my script, I create a named pipe, and open it as follows:

```
import os
import posix
import time

file_name = 'fifo.txt'
os.mkfifo(file_name)

f = posix.open(file_name, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK)
os.set_blocking(f, False)
```

Without yet having opened the file for reading elsewhere ( for instance, with `cat`), I start to write to the file in a loop.

```
base_line = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
s = base_line * 10000 + '\n'

while True:
    try:
        posix.write(f, s.encode())
    except BlockingIOError as e:
        print("Exception occurred: {}".format(e))
    time.sleep(.5)
```

When I then go to read from the named pipe with `cat`, I find that there was a partial-write that took place.

I am confused how I can know how many bytes were written in this instance.  Since the exception was thrown, I do not have access to the return value (num bytes written).  The documentation suggests that `BlockingIOError` has a property called `characters_written`, however when I try to access this field an `AttributeError` is raised.

In summary: How can I either avoid this partial write in the first place, or at least know how much was partially written in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.write` performs an unbuffered write. The docs state that `BlockingIOError` only has a `characters_written` attribute when a buffered write operation would block.

If any bytes were successfully written before the pipe became full, that number of bytes will be returned from `os.write`.  Otherwise, you'll get an exception.  Of course, something like a drive failure will also cause an exception, even if some bytes were written.  This is no different from how POSIX `write` works, except instead of returning -1 on error, an exception is raised.

If you don't like dealing with the exception, you can use a wrapper around the file descriptor, such as a `io.FileIO` object.  I've modified your code since it tries to write the entire buffer every time you looped back to the `os.write` call (if it failed once, it will fail every time):

```
import io
import os
import time

base_line = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
data = (base_line * 10000 + '\n').encode()

file_name = 'fifo.txt'
os.mkfifo(file_name)
fd = os.open(file_name, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK)
# os.O_NONBLOCK makes os.set_blocking(fd, False) unnecessary.

with io.FileIO(fd, 'wb') as f:
    written = 0
    while written < len(data):
        n = f.write(data[written:])
        if n is None:
            time.sleep(.5)
        else:
            written += n
```

BTW, you might use the `selectors` module instead of `time.sleep`; I noticed a slight delay when trying to read from the pipe because of the sleep delay, which shouldn't happen if you use the `selectors` module:

```
with io.FileIO(fd, 'wb') as f:
    written = 0
    sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
    sel.register(f, selectors.EVENT_WRITE)
    while written < len(data):
        n = f.write(data[written:])
        if n is None:
            # Wait here until we can start writing again.
            sel.select()
        else:
            written += n
    sel.unregister(f)
```

Some useful information can also be found in the answer to [POSIX named pipe (fifo) drops record in nonblocking mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61548122/12483061).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I indirectly got my answer from this :). I had assumed that the first exception-throwing write invocation was the partial write.  In fact, the partial write is totally valid (and checking the length as you show is the correct thing to do).  

On the rest - the sleeping instead of selectors was for demonstration code. In practice, this code is part of a larger execution loop.  Thanks again!

Comment: Will this approach degenerate into blocking writes?